# Flex Box Last Row element

Tags: css, flexbox

I am facing a problem in alignment of last row in flex box. I want to pull the element at left as we do in box model

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-container div {
  flex-basis: 31.33%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need even space

Then use `margin`. Here's a combination with `calc()`.

Simple math: 100% of full width - (3 elements in the row with the left and right margin, ergo, 6) divided by 3.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-container div {
  flex-basis: calc((100% - 6%)/3);
  margin: 1%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Update: adding the margin on the second element in each row:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-container > div {
  flex-basis: 32%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.flex-container > div:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its looks great. But I don't need padding between 1n and 3n Childs. Is there any solution?

Comment: @LogeshS padding or margin?

Comment: which container you don't want padding? In border container or without border container

Comment: To the .container @ Hiren. @ Vucko Padding... But this answer is fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In `.flex-container` class remove property `justify-content: space-between;` It is not needed.

**Try this one may be that will help you**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-container div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
  padding: 10px;
}
.flex-container div div { border: 1px solid #ccc;  padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
<div><div>1</div></div>
<div><div>1</div></div>
<div><div>1</div></div>
<div><div>1</div></div>
<div><div>1</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: He would also want an even space I guess.

Comment: I need Even space.

Comment: Its looks ok. But I don't need padding between 1n and 3n Childs.

Answer (score 1):

`justify-content: flex-start` will do what you want.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-container div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
</div>
```

**edit:**

If you need spaces between boxes you can do it like that:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-container div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-container div:nth-of-type(3n + 2),
.flex-container div:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {
  background: pink;
  margin-right: 30px;
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3 - 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
</div>
```

So what is going on here?

```
.flex-container div:nth-of-type(3n + 1),
.flex-container div:nth-of-type(3n + 2){
  margin-right: 30px;
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3 - 30px);
}
```

`nth-of-type(3n + 1)` is selecting every third sibling starting from first

`3n + 2` starting from second.

Then we adding margin-right to them (or margin-left if you want to select 3n+2 and 3n+3).

As an border-box will not calculate width of elements with margin, we need to subtract it from width with `calc()` in `flex-basis:` (which one in this case is equivalent to `width:`)

Comment: I need space between the Items.

Comment: Use margin/padding

Comment: I was edit post, now you have a nice way for margins.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-container div {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.flex-container div div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div><div>1</div></div>
  <div><div>1</div></div>
  <div><div>1</div></div>
  <div><div>1</div></div>
  <div><div>1</div></div>
</div>
```